# How buffering actions with redux-saga

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-saga

I need increase count variable on every action call in saga and after some time, for example 1500 ms, call func and clear count. How can I make it ?

Something like that:

```js
export function* example() {
  let count = 0;
  let timeout;

  const data = yield take(rootAction.adverts.likeAdvert.request)

  if (timeout) {
    clearTimeout(timeout)
  }

  count++;

  timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    // replace with eventChanel
    yield apiCall(count, data)

    count = 0
  }, 1500)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Javascript timeout, this can be solved very neatly with the powerful functionality of redux-saga itself, specifically the combination of `takeLatest` with the `delay` side effect.

Example:

```
export function* example() {
    const data = yield take(rootAction.adverts.likeAdvert.request);
    const count = yield select((state) => state.count);
    yield put({ type: COUNT_UPDATE, count: count + 1, data });
}

export function* listenForCount() {
    yield takeLatest(COUNT_UPDATE, function* handle(action) {
        yield delay(1500);
        yield put(COUNT_RESET);
        yield apiCall(action.count, action.data);
    });
}
```

With a reducer like this:

```
export function count(state = 0, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case COUNT_UPDATE:
            return action.count;
        case COUNT_RESET:
            return 0;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```